# NavigationBar back button disappears

Tags: iphone

I used codes below to display the uiimage on navigation bar

```
-(void)hideTopBanner:(bool)b;
{
    if(b)
    {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35 animations:^{

         UIView *bannerView =[self.navigationController.navigationBar viewWithTag:999];
            [bannerView setFrame:CGRectMake(-320, 8, 144, 30)];


        }];
    }
    else {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35 animations:^{



            UIView *bannerView =[self.navigationController.navigationBar viewWithTag:999];
            [bannerView setFrame:CGRectMake(88 , 8, 144, 30)];



        }];
    }
}
```

//--------------

```
UIImageView *bgImageView =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"topbg1.png"]] ;
[bgImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 46)];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:bgImageView];
bgImageView.tag=999;
[bgImageView release];
```

I try to use

```
  UIBarButtonItem *myBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
   myBarButtonItem.title = @back"; // or whatever text you want
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = myBarButtonItem;
    [myBarButtonItem release];
```

display a back button ,but nothing displayed

but when it navigates to another view controller.
The back button on navigation bar disappear.

Welcome any comment

Comment: Did you try setting any title to ViewController?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your new view controller (the one you're navigating to) has a title. I encountered this problem when my views were not set a title.

Answer (score 0):

If everything fails (setting title etc), use this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *myBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
[myBarButtonItem addTarget:self action:@selector(myBarButtonItemPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
myBarButtonItem.title = @"back"; // or whatever text you want
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = myBarButtonItem;
[myBarButtonItem release];

- (void)myBarButtonItemPressed
{
    // Do your stuff, like pop view controller
}
```